# Object default value?

Tags: javascript

I have not worked with Javascript for a while, but I seem to remember a thing that I can not get working. Can you please help me out?

I want to create an object `var testobject = {}` and then make some additional functions from page to page. My memory says something like:

```
var testobject = { extfunc : somerandomfunc ||false }
```

but it gives me the error "somerandomfunc is not defined", now i only want it to catch "somerandomfunc" on pages it exists and then default to "false" when it doesn't. How does one achieve this now a days?

Answer (score 4):

This more explicit version will work:

```js
var testobject = {
  extfunc: typeof somerandomfunc != 'undefined' ? somerandomfunc : false
}
```

Comment: So I have to run a shorthand IF ELSE to check if it exists? I'll try that, one sec.

Edit: Seems to work, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

use `typeof`

```
var testobject = { extfunc : typeof somerandomfunc!=='undefined'?somerandomfunc :false }
```

Answer (score 2):

To create an object

```
 var testobject = {};
```

To add a function inside the "testobject"

```
testobject.extfunc = typeof somerandomfunc === 'function' ? somerandomfunc : false;
```

Comment: I got the shorthand if-else to work. My object is a self-running object that loops itself basicly, and then I want to make a predefined variable to be called if exists or just skip it. I therefore needed it to be defaulted if no existed rather than expanding it below/after. Thanks for your reply!